# How can I change the a background image, depending on the size of the screen?

Tags: html, css, mobile, zurb-foundation

I am using Zurb foundation to handle my styling, I know there is a data interchange class for changing images based on screen size but not sure if you can use it to change the background image of a div?

```
background-image:image-url('img_home_first_bar.jpg');
```

Comment: Did you try using `media queries`?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using media queries as said in the comments by **Rahul Desai**.

## Example:

### HTML:

```
<div class="backgroundchange"></div>
```

### CSS:

```
.backgroundchange {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    .backgroundchange {
        background-image: url("backing1.png");
        background: blue;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 487px) and (max-width: 1079px) {
    .backgroundchange {
        background-image: url("backing2.png");
        background: green;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 487px) {
    .backgroundchange {
        background-image: url("backing3.png");
        background: red;
    }
}
```

So using these media queries you can set the CSS to change depending on what the window size is.

**Note:** Make the result window bigger and smaller to see the effect.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/byH2j/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as your problem is similar to the problem discussed here.

**[Background Image change with screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066794/background-image-change-with-screen-size)**.