# Different background src based on width size in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I would like to get a different background `scr` based on the width of the screen. How would I go about doing this? Also, can I disable a function for screen smaller than 480 pixels? The following code does not seem to work

```
$(window).ready(function() {
'use strict';
$.vegas('slideshow', {
        if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
            /* How to disable this fuction for resolution smaller than 480 ??? */
        } 
        else if ($(window).width() <= 720) {
            backgrounds:[
                { src:'images/bg-slider/720-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/720-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/720-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
            ]
        }
        else if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
            backgrounds:[
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1024-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1024-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1024-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
            ]
        }
        else if ($(window).width() <= 1280) {
            backgrounds:[
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1280-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1280-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1280-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
            ]
        }
        else if ($(window).width() <= 1440) {
            backgrounds:[
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1440-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1440-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1440-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
            ]
        }
        else if ($(window).width() <= 1920) {
            backgrounds:[
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1920-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1920-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
                { src:'images/bg-slider/1920-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
            ]
        }
})();
});
```

Comment: Show us the documentation of the slideshow. Search it, i think that there are an disable event.

Comment: Use media queries in CSS, it's cleaner, quicker and the proper way to do responsive Web design

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425423/how-can-i-change-the-a-background-image-depending-on-the-size-of-the-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/settings/) for Vegas, you'll notice two things:

1. `vegas` should be called on an element
2. the options passed to the method are an object

In the code you provided, the placement of the `if` statements isn't syntactically correct (it would be expecting `key: value` pairs of the object started and ended with the curly braces), but we *could* do something like this:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    var slides;
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 480) {
        // Do nothing, skip.
    }
    else if (width <= 720) {
        slides = [
            { src:'images/bg-slider/720-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/720-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/720-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
        ];
    }
    else if (width <= 1024) {
        slides = [
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1024-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1024-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1024-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
        ];
    }
    else if (width <= 1280) {
        slides = [
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1280-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1280-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1280-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
        ];
    }
    else if (width <= 1440) {
        slides = [
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1440-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1440-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1440-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
        ];
    }
    else if (width <= 1920) {
        slides = [
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1920-1.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1920-2.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'images/bg-slider/1920-3.jpg', fade:1000 }
        ];
    }
    if (slides) {
        $("#slideshow").vegas('slideshow', {
            slides: slides
        });
    } else {
        // Window width too big or small.
    }
});
```

Notice that we only initialize the slideshow when `slides` is set, which gives you the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sizes = [720, 1024, 1280, 1440, 1920];

function slidesForScreenSize(size) {
    return $.map([1, 2, 3], function (n) {
        return {
            src: 'images/bg-slider/' + size + '-' + n + '.jpg',
            fade: 1000
        }
    });

}

$(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 480) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
            if (width <= sizes[i]) {
                $('body').vegas({
                    slides: slidesForScreenSize(sizes[i])
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```